# A $3\times3$ matrix $P$ is such that, $P^3 = P$. Then the eigenvalues of $P$ are?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Recently I came across a question [here](https://gate.iitkgp.ac.in/documents/gatepapers/2016/ee_2016.pdf) p.25 question 7. This is a question from the GATE EE 2016 exam. But I was having difficulty in analyzing the question as to whether it has a definite answer or not based on the given information in the question. Below I share two approaches of my peers and two of them came up with two different approaches with two different answers.

---

> A $3\times3$ matrix $P$ is such that, $P^3 = P$. Then the eigenvalues of $P$ are:
>
> $\quad A. \quad1, 1, -1$
>
> $\quad B.\quad1, 0.5 + j0.866, 0.5 - j0.866$
>
> $\quad C \quad1, -0.5 + j0.866, -0.5 - j0.866$
>
> $\quad D \quad 0, 1, -1$
> $\tag {$\text{GATE 2016 EE Set 2}$}$

This is a single option correct question.

One of my peers came up with the following approach:

> Let $\lambda$ be a eigen value of matrix $P$ and $X$ be the corresponding eigen vector so:
> $$PX=\lambda X \tag 1$$
> $$\implies P^3 X=\lambda^3 X$$
> $$\implies PX=\lambda^3X \quad\text{[As it is given that $P^3=P$]}\tag 2$$
> From $(1)$ and $(2)$ we have:
> $$\lambda^3X=\lambda X$$
> $$\implies (\lambda^3-\lambda)X=\mathbb{O}_{3\times 1}$$
> But as $X \neq \mathbb{O}_{3\times 1}$ we have:
> $$\lambda^3-\lambda=0 \implies \lambda=0,1,-1$$
> So option (D) seems to be correct

But my another peer came up with a specific example:

> Let $P=\begin{pmatrix}
> 1 & 0 & 0\\
> 0 & 0 & 1 \\
> 0 & 1 & 0
> \end{pmatrix}$,
>
> so $P^2=\mathbb{I}_{3\times 3}$  $\implies P^3=P$
>
> Let $\lambda$ be a eigen value of matrix $P$ and $X$ be the corresponding eigen vector so:
> $$PX=\lambda X $$
> $$\implies (P-\lambda\mathbb{I}_{3\times 3})= X$$
> For $X$ to non zero we should have:
> $$det(P-\lambda\mathbb{I}_{3\times 3})=0$$
> $$\implies\begin{vmatrix}
> 1-\lambda & 0 & 0\\
> 0 & 0-\lambda & 1 \\
> 0 & 1 & 0-\lambda
> \end{vmatrix}=0$$
> $$\implies \lambda=-1,1,1$$

---

*What is the problem which has crept in the solution?* I guess I and my peers are missing out something. What are we missing out so that we are unable to generate all possible viable solutions?

I myself tried to approach as follows:

> $$P^3=P$$ $$\implies |P^3|=|P|$$ $$\implies |P|^3=|P|$$$$\implies |P|^3-|P|=0$$ $$\implies |P|=0,1,-1$$
> For case: $|P|=0$ I have one eigen value as $0$,but I have clue as to how to find the other two.
>
> For the other two cases of $|P|$ I could not proceed further...

Comment: None of the options is correct, just take $P=0$.

Comment: The zero matrix has only zero eigenvalues (as @TheSilverDoe points out), and the identity matrix has only unit eigenvalues.  So the question cannot be answered on its own basis; if it is answerable at all, it must be of the type "only one of the following answers can be correct."

Comment: $P$ can certainly have eigenvalues $1,1,-1$ or $0,1,-1$, so the question as stated is wrong, even if @BrianTung's suggestion is correct. Are you sure you have given us the complete question? Were there any other conditions on $P$?

Comment: Yeah, something's wrong.  You can have a diagonal matrix $P$ with whatever combination of $0, 1, -1$ along the diagonal you like, and those will be the eigenvalues, and also $P = P^3$.  As @TonyK suggests, something must be missing.

Comment: I have added the question source from the GATE old question  paper database. It was a question from GATE EE 2016 paper. But it seems from the accepted answers (final answer keys based on which students were evaluated) there either A or D where given as viable answers... The question specifically seems odd to me as there is no definite way I guess using which one can reach to a definite answer

Comment: I would recommend moving the question source link to the **beginning** of the post, to establish upfront that you are quoting *verbatim* from an exam, because as various comments already note, there's something wrong in the wording of the question.

Comment: I would also recommend rewording your question itself to make it clear that you're wondering if the exam question is well posed, e.g., something along the lines of "I am wondering if the following question from [source link] makes sense:..."

Comment: @BarryCipra I did it, please can you check it once... is it ok now?

Comment: @AbhishekGhosh, that's an excellent edit.

Comment: @BarryCipra Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The solution by your first peer tells you that eigenvalues can only be $0$, $1$ or $-1$.

But this doesn't mean they are exactly that, in fact any combination $(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3)$ with $\lambda_i\in\{-1,0,1\}$ is possible.

With $(0,0,0)$ a possible candidate is the zero matrix , with $(1,1,1)$ a possible candidate is the identity matrix, with $(-1,1,1)$ you second peer example, etc.

So we can rule out answers $B$ and $C$ for sure.

Without any more precisions $A$ or $D$ could fit, but as said previously it's not even mandatory.

Adding the reasonable condition $P^2\neq P$ would rule out the zero and identity matrix, but it still doesn't make a difference in regard to choices $A, D$ has both $\operatorname{diag}(1,1,-1)$ and $\operatorname{diag}(0,1,-1)$ would satisfy the problem.

So the question is definitely ill-posed.

---

Edit: note for your solution since eigenvalues are among $\{-1,0,1\}$ the product of three of such integers is among the same set, and so is the determinant. But this does not really help you in the reciprocal problem of finding the eigenvalues knowing only the possible values of the determinant.

In fact the approach given by your first peer is I think the best one, you just misinterpreted the result considering the eigenvalues should all be distinct, while you just need to select them in this $\{-1,0,1\}$ pool with possible repetitions.

Comment: Could you just help me out in one point. How do you say that `But this doesn't mean they are exactly that, in fact any combination (λ1,λ2,λ3) with λi∈{−1,0,1} is possible.` Did you come to this conclusion using some mathematics. Or hit and trial. If it was reached using hit and trial, it does not possibly help us conclude that B and C are out of the picture. So definitely you came to that conclusion using some mathematics. Please could just include that in your answer as well then it shall help a lot. :)

Comment: Is it something like this? Let $P=diag(a,b,c)$ then $P^3=diag(a^3, b^3, c^3)$. $P^3=P$ so $a^3=a$;$b^3=b$;$c^3=c$ so $a=0,1,-1$ ;$b=0,1,-1$ and $c=0,1,-1$. Based on this $(\lambda_1, \lambda_2,\lambda_3) \in \{0,1,-1\}^3$. But this approach does not consider matrices of my second peer. How to say definitively that the eigen values are all and only the combination of $\{0,1,-1\}$. Is it at all possible to say something like that? Otherwise I guess we cannot possibly rule out B and C. Because there might be a matrix which are overlooking having the eigen values in B or C.

Answer (score 0):

If $P$ is not the zero matrix, and as `zwim` noted, if $P^2 \ne P$ and $P^3=P,$ then we can use the Cayley-Hamilton theorem, since $P^3-P=0_{n\times n}$ this means that your eigenvalues would be the roots of $\lambda^3-\lambda = 0.$ But there a lot of `if`s and I agree that the problem is not properly stated.

Answer (score -2):

You have,
$$
P^3=P\\
P^{-1}P=1\\
$$
where $P^{-1}$ is the inverse of $P$ and the $1$ in the equation represents a 3x3 matrix with ones in the diagonal and zeros in off diagonal elements (the assumtion is that $P$ is invertible).
$$
P^{-1}P^3=P^2=P^{-1}P=1\\
P^{-1}P^2=P=P^{-1}\\
P=P^{-1}
$$
That is $P$ is "involutory".  Write the eigenvalue equation,
$$
Px=\lambda x\\
P^{-1}Px=\lambda P^{-1}x\\
x=\lambda^2 x \\
(1-\lambda^2)x=0
$$
and thus the eigenvalues can only be $\pm 1$

Comment: What is $P^{-1}$ ?

Comment: Sorry, but $P^{-1}$ isn't guaranteed to exist. If any of the eigenvalues are $0$ then the inverse isn't defined.